What does it mean to carry 'a fraction of the proton's spin'?
The proton spin crisis is an open problem in physics regarding the origin of the spin of the proton. The problem is described as some "fraction of the proton's spin" being unaccounted for. But what exactly does the statement in quotes even mean? It is quite confusing at first glance, since the proton's total spin is $\hbar/2$. How can we talk about fractions of $\hbar/2$, which is the smallest unit of angular momentum in quantum mechanics?
My guess (which admittedly doesn't make sense, for reasons I'll mention at the end) would be that the statement has something to do with the components of the superposition of the proton's internal particles. There are many ways to attain a composite spin 1/2 particle; we could put two quarks in a singlet state (0 spin) and leave the third unpaired. Or we could add a fourth virtual quark, pair the four quarks into singlets, and then have some additional virtual particle 'carry the entirety' of the proton's spin. If we add these and other states in superposition, then the relative weights of this superposition could be interpreted as the relative contributions of different particles to the total spin.
However even if partially correct, the above explanation cannot be the whole story; baryon number is conserved, and so even if we consider virtual particles, the number of quarks in the proton must be odd. Therefore the contribution to spin from quarks will always have $m_{s,\text{tot}} = \hbar(2n+1)/2$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, and thus once again they are contributing the entirety of the proton's spin (or more).

In the wikipedia link that you yourself referenced, in the part about subsequent work, the article described the state of affairs as it stands today, and in it is described a lot of what is being meant. What it is that you want us to explain to you?

I've read the section you refer to three times now, and I still don't see anything addressing my question there. It repeatedly uses the notion of fractions of the proton's total spin. My question is asking what this notion means in the first place. The statement 'fraction of the nucleon spin carried in quark spin is about 30%' does not make any sense to me, because the smallest unit of angular momentum is 1/2, which is already the total value of the proton's spin.

Interpreting these fractions to represent subdivisions of the minimal unit of angular momentum, $\hbar/2$ seems obviously wrong. I've tried to make clear in my question why my 'best guess understanding' also runs into apparent contradiction. So I am asking for a correct explanation for what this could mean.

Now, this is a far better question: You should edit your original question to make it clear that this is what it is you are asking for. A partial answer is that, in order for the mathematics to work out correctly, we need to start from the basics and consider all the QCD monsters coming in, and because they are all extended wavefunctions, probably little packets of that everywhere in space. In that way, the spin is broken into tiny parts and would not be the complete quanta right from the get-go.

OK I edited the question to hopefully improve clarity. Is the first paragraph clear now at least?

Are you comfortable with the QCD Parton picture of the proton as a composite of an infinity of gluons, quarks, and antiquarks, described by normalized continuous distributions and how the normalized orbital angular momentum and partial spin distributions tally up?

I have heard of the Parton picture, but I haven't learned about it in detail. Hopefully the essence of the question can be illustrated even with simple, nonrelativistic examples? Is 'fractions of $\hbar/2$' only a meaningful statement in the parton picture but not any simpler toy model?

You will not be able to illustrate the “fractions” bit with a toy bound state of a finite number of constituents. The (bogus) “spin crisis” is basically a misunderstanding of the Parton picture.

@CosmasZachos Can you expand into an answer? Back when I was active in research I would ask this question at conferences, and I never really got a satisfactory answer.

Can't do it better than Jaffe. The point is the q-numbers of a baryon are expectation values of spin and orbital angular momentum of quark-antiquark-gluon weakly coupled distributions in x, a scaling momentum variable. The baryons are shaped by infinite-dimensional distribution functions....

What is usually called proton spin is actually the proton's total internal angular momentum $J$. There are multiple ways to couple the various spins and orbital momenta of the quarks and gluons inside a proton to form a state with $J=1/2$.
Edit:
As an example, a single particle with L=1 and S=1/2 can form a J=1/2 state. In this state you could say that its spin contributes -100% and its orbital moment +200% to the final J value. In the much more complex system of the proton this can take a broad range of values.
This also shows that it is incorrect to say ‘Therefore the contribution to spin from quarks will always have ms,tot=ℏ(2n+1)/2 with n∈Z, and thus once again they are contributing the entirety of the proton's spin (or more).’ The first part is in correct because not all quark spins need to be aligned. The second part is incorrect because of the counterexample I gave in the first edit.
If any downvoter has a better answer, submit it.

You should have checked with the OP to see what it is he/she wanted answered rather than write a generic answer that clearly isn't want the OP wants.

@naturallyInconsistent The answer is here. Exactly what is the OP asking in your opinion? You clearly stated before that you have no idea and now you are lecturing about it.
